# memory management using linked list

Tags: java, memory-management, linked-list

This is  a homework question in relation to memory management implementation using linked lists.
Each memory process requests of a particular size of memory that must be contiguously large enough to fit the memory and then allocate the process.When a job terminates,its allowed memory becomes free.
This is the java code I wrote for this.

```
public class PartitionNode{
    int beginAddress;
    int endAddress;
    boolean holeFree;
    int processId;
    PartitionNode next;

    public PartitionNode(int begin,int end){
         beginAddress=begin;
         endAddress=end;
         holeFree=true;
         processId=-1;
         next=null;


    }
    public PartitionNode(){}
    public PartitionNode(int begin,int end,int i){
        beginAddress=begin;
        endAddress=end;
        holeFree=false;
        processId=i;

    }

}

public class Partition{
    private  PartitionNode head;
    public PartitionNode current;

public  int begin;
public int end;
public PartitionNode newPartition;
public Partition(int beginAddress,int endAddress,int a){
    head=new PartitionNode(beginAddress,endAddress);
    begin=beginAddress;
    end=endAddress;
    current=head;
}
public Partition(int beginAddress,int endAddress){
    current=new PartitionNode(beginAddress,endAddress);

}
public void addProcess(int size,int id){
    if((current.endAddress-current.beginAddress>=size)&& current.holeFree==true){
        newPartition=new PartitionNode(current.beginAddress,current.beginAddress+size-1,id);
        newPartition.next=refresh();

        System.out.println("beginAddress"+newPartition.beginAddress);
        System.out.println("endAddress"+newPartition.endAddress);

    }

}

 public void print(){
    System.out.println("beginAddress"+newPartition.beginAddress);
     System.out.println("endAddress"+newPartition.endAddress);
 }


public   PartitionNode refresh(){
    current=new PartitionNode(newPartition.endAddress+1,end);
        return current;

}
public void deleteProcess(int process){
    PartitionNode temp=head;

    while(temp.next!=null){
        System.out.println(temp.processId);
        temp=temp.next;

    }

}



public static void main (String args[]){
    Partition p=new Partition(300,3000,1);
    p.addProcess(500,1);
    p.addProcess(800,2);
    p.addProcess(400,3);
    p.deleteProcess(5);
    System.out.println(p.head.beginAddress);
}


}
```

I have two questions.
I have to have a constructor as

```
public Partition(int beginAddress,int endAddress,int a){
        head=new PartitionNode(beginAddress,endAddress);
        begin=beginAddress;
        end=endAddress;
        current=head;
    }
```

where **int a** is of no use.It is just there to make sure that this constructor's argument list is different from

```
 public Partition(int beginAddress,int endAddress){
        current=new PartitionNode(beginAddress,endAddress);

    }
```

Because of this now I have to call as `Partition p=new Partition(300,3000,1);` with **1** being useless.
How can I get rid of this problem.

My next question is implementing method to  delete a process.

```
public void deleteProcess(int process){
        PartitionNode temp=head;

        while(temp.next!=null){
            System.out.println(temp.processId);
            temp=temp.next;

        }

    }
```

The while loop doesn't get executed.What's wrong with that?

Can someone please help me to correct the mistakes?

Comment: For your second problem using your debugger will help you identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Comment-as-answer:

You should split this into two questions. You can get rid of the need for the useless concstructor arg by using static factory methods to create your object, rather than the constructor directly. They allow you to name different ways to create an instance of a class. Make the constructor private while having public static methods that return a new instance of the class. That will allow you to use the same parameters for a "constructor", while having the ability to create and return a unique instance:

```
class Example {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          Object first = Object.createObject(1, 2);
          Object second = Object.createAndStore(1, 2);
     }
}

class Object {
     private int a, b;

     //private constructor ensures need for methods
     private Object(int a, int b) {
          //create node
     }

     //the factory methods
     public static Object createObject(int a, int b) {
          return new Object(a, b);
     }

      public static Object createAndStore(int a, int b) {
          Object ob = new Object();
          //store vars using ob
         return ob;
     }
}
```

As for the loop part, where do you init `temp.next`? I see you initialize `temp` with `head`, but I don't see where you initialize it.

Also, I highly suggest changing the title of this question to more fit the issues